# How to catch raised exception in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rake-task

I have a rake task that loops through rows in CSV file, and inside that loop, there's a begin/rescue block to catch any possible raised exception. But when I run it, it keeps on saying 'rake aborted!' and it is not entering the rescue block

```
CSV.foreach(path, :headers => true) do |row|
  id = row.to_hash['id'].to_i
  if id.present?
    begin
      # call to mymethod
    rescue => ex
      puts "#{ex} error executing task"
    end
  end
end
...
def mymethod(...)
  ...
  begin
    response = RestClient.post(...)
  rescue => ex
    raise Exception.new('...')
  end
end
```

Expected: It should finish looping all the rows of the CSV

Actual result: It stops after reaching the 'raise' exception saying that:

> rake aborted!
>
> Exception: error message here
>
> ...
>
> Caused by:
>
> RestClient::InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: This looks like it could be a different issue - perhaps it's worth including your actual code @OdethA.? Is there a call to RestClient elsewhere in the task that could be throwing this?

Comment: @SRack, I edited the sample code above including the structure of the method being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by just commenting out the line that is raising an exception because it seems like it the quickest fix for now.

```
# raise Exception.new('...')
```

I'm still open to other suggestions if there are any better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next` to skip the faulty step of loop:

```
CSV.foreach(path, :headers => true) do |row|
  id = row.to_hash['id'].to_i
  if id.present?
    begin
      method_which_doing_the_staff
    rescue SomethingException
      next
    end
  end
end
```

And raise the exception inside your method:

```
def method_which_doing_the_staff
  stuff
  ...
  raise SomethingException.new('hasd')
end
```

Comment: Hi Barmic, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I also did try that before. But it still got stopped by the exception. I updated the question to show the similar error I received when I run the task.

Comment: I don't think this would make any difference @barmic? `next` would be useful if used based on a condition, though switching out `puts` for this wouldn't change anything.